# How can I import a single font-awesome icon?

Tags: sass, icons, font-awesome

I am attempting to import fa-carot-down, but I don't want to import the whole library. I need a single icon, but I'm not sure how to include it.

I'm using Webpack and SASS, if that makes any difference.

Alternatively, any means to get a carot icon for my dropdown would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [**IcoMoon**](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) and [**Fontello**](http://fontello.com/)  as it helps you create your *own library of fonts*.

Furthur you can bundle it together with **webpack** to *import* the *necessary* icons

Now *svg's* are supported in **IcoMoon**